# not only ... but also

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

> "Not only do the children need new clothes, but also need new bookbags."
>
> " The Children not only need clothes but also need new bookbags."

Which one do you often write or say?

Are these the same? Are they correct?

Comment: In the last 3 days you have posted over 20 questions but you have not marked any answers as correct. Hasn't anyone been able to help you so far?

Comment: +1 @fluffy It's not just for the past three days. Check the profile, it's been the scene right from the day one. I think she posts **every** sentence she comes across and never selects the answer. This puts wrong impression and many might stop answering her questions. I'll commit that I'm one of them.

Comment: How can I mark any answer??

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @nima_persian just by ticking the 'check' sign under the answer you like. It's grayed sign under vote-counting just left to the answer. Spend some time and do that now. That'll be helpful for you as well as others to learn.

Comment: Ok. What about my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Not only do the children need clothes, but **they** also need new
>   bookbags"

Would be the correct way of writing the first sentence.

> "Children need not only clothes, but also new bookbags"

Would be the correct way to write the second sentence.

They mean different things though: the first refers to specific children (**the** children), the second refers to children in general.

Comment: For the first half of the second sentence, I thought reversing the order of the verb(need) and the adv(not only) may better meet the grammaticality of parallelism. My version is: Children need not only clothes, but also new bookbags.

Comment: I agree. Here is an example of similar "not only...but also" mistakes: https://www.dailywritingtips.com/5-faulty-not-only-but-also-sentences/